# SQL:How do i get the row that has the max value of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data a set which is already grouped by `Person` and `Class` columns and I use this query for this process:

```
SELECT Person,Class, MAX(TimeSpent) as MaxTimeSpent 
FROM Persons 
GROUP BY Person,Class
```

Output:

```
Person   Class    MaxTimeSpent 
--------|--------|-------------|
MJ      |   0    | 0           |
MJ      |   1    | 659         |
MJ      |   2    | 515         |
```

What I want to do is to get the row that has the maximum `Class` value in this data set (which is the 3rd row for this example).

How can I do this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @StuartLC `TOP 1` wont work since i use `WHERE` caluse to make easier to test my query.

Comment: In that case, search for a Group Wise Maximum - a good strategy is to use the partitions to group the data and use `ROW_NUMBER` (no ties) or `RANK` (with ties) to number the rows within each group, ordered by `Class`, and then to filter out just the Row / Rank = 1 rows.

Comment: See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
    (SELECT Person,
           Class,
           MAX(TimeSpent) AS MaxTimeSpent 
    FROM Persons AS P
    WHERE Person = 'MJ'
    GROUP BY Person, Class) AS T
WHERE T.class = (
      SELECT MAX(class) FROM Persons AS P
      WHERE P.person = T.person)
```

Comment: Hi @fabulaspb, yep. nice one

Answer (score 1):

You can use cte for that.

```
 declare @Persons table (person nvarchar(10),Class int ,TimeSpent int)

insert into @Persons
select 'MJ',0,0 union all
select 'MJ',1,659 union all
select 'MJ',2,515 


;with cte
as(
SELECT Person,Class,TimeSpent , row_number() over(partition by Person  order by Class desc )  as RN
FROM @Persons 
)
select * from cte where RN=1
```

Solution 2 :With Out Cte:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Person
        ,Class
        ,TimeSpent
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Class DESC) AS RN FROM @Persons
    ) t WHERE t.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY This:

```
declare @t table (Person  varchar (20),Class    int ,MaxTimeSpent int )
insert into @t VALUES ('MJ',0,0)
insert into @t VALUES ('MJ',1,659)
insert into @t VALUES ('MJ',2,515)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @t ORDER BY 2 DESC

--OR
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE Class = (SELECT max(class) FROM @t)

-- OR
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY Class DESC) Record_Count FROM @t
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Top 1 Person,Class, MAX(TimeSpent) as MaxTimeSpent 
FROM Persons 
GROUP BY Person,Class order by Class desc